# How to check check the password from login with the password hashed by bcrypt in register?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, bcrypt

I'm trying to create a signup/login page. I'm using Nodejs, pug, mongoose, bcrypt. I'm storing the password from the register or sign up page to the database after hashing it. I'm unable to use

```
const user= new login.findone({email: req.body.email})
if(user){
   bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, result) {
    // result == true
});
}
```

as this gives me a false result. 
I also believe that the findOne({email: req.body.email}) is not working correctly or there is some error in there too.

Here is the index page handling these validations

```js
const express = require('express');
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;

//Mongoose

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var registration = require('../models/registrations') //Important
var login = require('../models/login') //Important

var blogpost = require('../models/blog')

//Routes

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------REGISTER/SIGN UP
router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.render('./home.pug')
})

router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('register',{ title: 'Register' });
});

router.post('/register', [
    check('name')
      .isLength({ min: 5 })
      .withMessage('> Please enter a name'),
    check('email')
      .isLength({min: 14})
      .withMessage('> Please enter an email'),
    check('password')
    .isLength({min:6})
  ],(req, res)  => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    
    var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds);
    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);

    var emailcheck = registration.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    emailcheck.then(emailcheck => {
    if (emailcheck){
      res.render('register', {emailERROR: '> Email already in use!\n',  data: req.body,})
    }else{
      if (errors.isEmpty()) {
        const regis = new registration({
          name: req.body.name,
          email: req.body.email,
          password: hash,
        });
        regis.save()
          .then(() => { res.render('register', {successMSG: '> Succesfully Registered!',  data: req.body,})
        console.log(regis) })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.send('Sorry! Something went wrong.');
            
      })}
  
       else {
        res.status(422).render('register', {title: 'Registration form', errors: errors.array(), data: req.body,});
      }
    }
    })
console.log(req.body)
  })
//Register-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------LOGIN
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login',{ title: 'Login' });
});

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  //Empty
});





//Login-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------BLOG
router.get('/blog', (req, res) => {
  res.render('blog',{ title: 'Blog' });
});
router.post('/blog', (req, res) => {
  const bp= new blogpost(req.body)
  bp.save()
    .then(()=>{
      res.render('blog', {successMSG:'>Succesfully Posted!'})
    })

  
});
//Blog-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x

router.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.render('about',{ title: 'About' });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, result) {}
```

Can you elaborate on what you've entered as a value of hash here? If everything has gone correctly up to here then below code should work correctly for you.

```
const user= new login.findone({email: req.body.email})
if(user){
   console.log(user.password) // Check to see if password from database is returned as expected or not
   bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, user.passsword, function(err, result) {
       // Your codes
   });
}
```

Comment: I think instead of having login.findOne({email:req.body.email}), we should use registration.findOne({email:req.body.email}) because registration is the one holding the object in which we have initially stored the details such as Name, Email, and hashed password.

Instead of myPlaintextPassword or the password received from the login post, I have used req.body.password. And instead of hash, I have used user.password. The console.log(user.password) gives undefined. 


I feel like I have confused myself.

Comment: router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
const user= registration.findOne({email: req.body.email})
if(user){
   console.log(user.password) // Check to see if password from database is returned as expected or not
   bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.passsword, function(err, result) {
       // Your codes
   });
}
});